# Segfault calling a function with template typename in c++

Tags: c++, containers

I have a project that asks me to recreate containers in c++. I wanted to create a print function for my vector container.

I don't really understand why the code below is not working. I event tried replacing the typename T with int but I have a segfault as soon as I call the function (it does not even try to read inside the function).

With the same thing inside the main, I have what I expect..

Can you help me out ? Thanks

```
template <typename T>
void        vprint(ft::Vector<T> obj)
{
    for (ft::IteratorVector<T> it = obj.begin(); it != obj.end(); it++)
        std::cout << *it << " " << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    ft::Vector<int> vec_int((size_t)3, (int)42);
    for (ft::IteratorVector<int> it = vec_int.begin(); it != vec_int.end(); it++)
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    vprint(vec_int);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Notice that you copy the vector on function call. This is probably not by design. The argument type should be `const ft::Vector<T>&`.

Comment: Try pass `obj` by reference, if it works then, probably your problems stem from incorrect implemention of 3/5 rules for your container.

Comment: Yes, if it works when passing by reference this does not mean that the problem is fixed. I cant stress this enough.

Comment: It is very likely that the copy constructor does not work properly. Please show the code of  `ft::Vector(const ft::Vector&)`...

Comment: Thank you for your answers. If I use "const ft::Vector<T> &obj", it works fine but I need to use "ft::IteratorVector<const T>" in the function. Do you know why it works in that way? I'm still learning a lot about the differences between C and C++. 

For the copy constructor :
Vector<T>& operator= (const Vector& x)
{
 clear();
 insert(begin(), x.begin(), x.end());
 return (*this);
}
(insert and clear seem to be working fine in my other tests)